# javascript click action triggered two actions

Tags: javascript

```
I have the following html:

<div class="title-block">
    <span class="date">Apr 09, 2013</span>
    <span class="invoice">Invoice #1365512756</span>
    <span class="retail-price">Rp 270000</span>
    <span class="arvo-regular button green confirm-payment" data-id="2">Confirm Payment</span>
    <img src="/bundles/shopiousmain/img/dashboard-li-down-arrow.png">
</div>
```

The class title-block has a javascript click action tied to it and the class button also has a click action tied to it. The issue is that when I click on the button it also triggers the title-block click action. How do I make it so that the click doesn't propagate?

Comment: are you using jQuery? is so, have you tried `e.stopPropagation()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this if you are using jquery

```
$("#buttonClass").click(function(e) {
   // mouse click on button
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

JS

```
function doSomething (e) {
  var event = e || window.event;
  if (event.stopPropagation) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  } else {
    event.cancelBubble = true;
  } 
}
```